# Populate checkbox from JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am having trouble trying to re-populate a form with has come from a JSON object. I have used JSON.stringify(name) and for the value as well and it returns me the type of data format I think might work. But can't seem to get in the $.each method

```
 function fetchOrderFromLocalStorage() {
    PROCESS_SAVE = true;

    var mcs = localStorage.getItem(REPORTS_KEY);
    console.log(mcs);

    var jsn = JSON.parse(mcs);
    console.log(jsn);

    if (mcs.length == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    $.each(jsn, function (name, val) {
        var $el = $("input[name='" + name + "']"),
            type = $el.attr('type');

        console.log(JSON.stringify(name) + ":" + JSON.stringify(val));

        switch (type) {
            case 'checkbox':
                $el.attr('checked', 'checked');
                break;
            case 'radio':
                $el.filter('[value="' + val + '"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
                break;
            default:
                $el.val(val);
        }
    });
    //console.log(jsn);
    //for (var i = 0; i < jsn.length; i++) {
    //    var formInput = jsn[i];
    //    $("form input[name='" + formInput.name + "']").val(formInput.value);
    //}
}
```

The commented out code at the bottom works, but I want to populate checkboxs as well so I have tried some code from here that has been checked to work. So I am trying it but my data is not in the correct format. I think I want JSON.Stringify() as the sonsole give me the correct result according to jQuery docs.

[image: Console result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
function fetchOrderFromLocalStorage() {
    PROCESS_SAVE = true;

    var mcs = localStorage.getItem(REPORTS_KEY);
    console.log(mcs);

    var jsn = JSON.parse(mcs);
    console.log(jsn);

    if (mcs.length == 0) {
        return false;
    }


    for (var i = 0; i < jsn.length; i++) {
        var formInput = jsn[i],
            $el = $("input[name='" + formInput.name + "']"),
            type = $el.attr('type');

        switch (type) {
         case 'checkbox':
          $el.attr('checked', 'checked');
          break;
         case 'radio':
          $el.filter('[value="'+formInput.value+'"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
          break;
         default:
          $el.val(formInput.value);
        }
    }
}
```